# PHP Sort Array Returned From FTP Server

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array returned from my home NAS FTP server:

```
$arr = array (
  0 => 'FOLDER./Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]',
  1 => './Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/DESC.txt',
  2 => './Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/NUMBERS_CONTACT.vbs',
  3 => './Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/paris.vacation.2018.5month-kodak.mkv',
  4 => './Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/paris.vacation.2018.5month-kodak.dbs',
  5 => 'FOLDER./Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak',
  6 => './Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/DESC.txt',
  7 => './Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/NUMBERS_CONTACT.vbs',
  8 => 'FOLDER./Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/Family',
  9 => './Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/Subs/2_IMG00536.jpg',
  10 => './Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/Subs/3_IMG00537.jpg',
  11 => './Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/Vacation.Dubai.2018.Center-Kodak.mp4',
  12 => './Vacation.2019.5Month.Sweden-Kodak.mp4',
);
```

As you can see i have many folders of my vacation and now i im writing html/css/jquery photo album but i need to get first in php correct order above needs to output:

```
[0] => FOLDER./Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]
[1] => ./Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/DESC.txt
[2] => ./Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/NUMBERS_CONTACT.vbs
[3] => ./Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/paris.vacation.2018.5month-kodak.mkv
[4] => ./Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/paris.vacation.2018.5month-kodak.dbs
[5] => ./Vacation.Paris.2018.5Month-Kodak[town]/Vacation.Dubai.2018.Center-Kodak.mp4
[6] => FOLDER./Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak
[7] => ./Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/DESC.txt
[8] => ./Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/NUMBERS_CONTACT.vbs
[9] => FOLDER./Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/Family
[10] => ./Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/Subs/2_IMG00536.jpg
[11] => ./Vacation.Dubai.2018-Kodak/Subs/3_IMG00537.jpg
[12] => ./Vacation.2019.5Month.Sweden-Kodak.mp4
```

This is code that member from this forum try but it is not working correctly:

https://3v4l.org/208ol

So if you could help me modify above code so that i can get desired output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This uses `usort` to do the work and there is a bit of fiddling needed to get the sort order your after.

The first part is extracting the year from the string - it's assumed that it will be something like `xxxxx 2020 xxxxx` which is why it uses the second element from the regex used here.  Then it will remove FOLDER only from the front of the string to ensure it isn't removed anywhere else.  Then to get the order 'right', it uses the year followed by the processed string...

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    $f = "FOLDER";
    if ( substr( $a, 0, strlen($f)) == $f ) {
        $a = substr( $a, strlen($f));
    }
    $y1 = preg_split("/\D+/", $a)[1];
    if ( substr( $b, 0, strlen($f)) == $f ) {
        $b = substr( $b, strlen($f));
    }
    $y2 = preg_split("/\D+/", $b)[1];
    return $y1.$a <=> $y2.$b;
});
print_r($arr);
```

This uses the spaceship operator for the comparison, which is PHP 7+ only.

Comment: This is great but i found just one think that is not doing right....you can see: https://3v4l.org/8NoDI as you can see all is right but i need to return 6 line before 4 and 5 line because i have ul and li elements that is showing my folders and subfolders so if you can make small correction to above code to show 6 line before 4 and 5 because now as is shown line 6 is after subfolder and i need it above subfolder so that i can show first main folder and then subfolder...

Comment: Your asking for something that is quite complicated, to try and understand the hierarchy of folders would take a lot more work.

Comment: I know..but above code and yours code needs only to sort array so that it display files in main folder and files in subfolder...this is what i have organized from myvacation on NAS...so if is not possible...then it is ok..thanks for your help